# send the POST value after redirecting from Login in mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

**Scenario**
I am trying to build the forum in my admin panel using asp.net MVC 3 where only authorized user can update new post and comment on post. Below is my comment function of PostsController

```
  [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Comment(int id, string name, string email, string body)
        {
            Post post = GetPost(id);
            Comment comment = new Comment();
            User CurrentUser = repository.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
            comment.UserID = CurrentUser.ID;
            comment.Post = post;
            comment.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
            comment.Name = User.Identity.Name;
            comment.Email = email;
            comment.Body = body;
            model.AddToComments(comment);
            model.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = id });

        }
```

**Problem:**
If someone comment on the post who is not logged-on, page is redirected to login page and after logged-on with authorized access, post value of the comment form is not identified by Comment action. code for comment form is:

```
 <form action="@Href("~/Posts/Comment/" + post.ID)" method ="post">
            <input type="text" id="commentNamePrompt" name="name" />
            Name (required) 
            <br />
            <input type="text" id="commentEmailPrompt" name="email" />
            Email (optional)
            <br />
            <textarea id="commentBodyInput" name="body" rows="10" cols="60"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" id="commentSubmitInput" name="submit" value="Submit!" />
            </form>
```

**Error**

```
This property cannot be set to a null value.
```

**Tried:**
I have try logging first to the site and commenting on post and it works fine
I am sure that the error is happened due to model post value  not passed after redirected to and from the login page.
How can I redirect to authorized page with comment form post value updated by unauthorized user.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no built-in functionality to support such things in MVC, you either need to extend `Action Filters` for this or think of some other way round.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way is to persist your comment fields into an alternative logon form as hidden fields. This can be done in the AuthorizeAttribute by intercepting the unauthorized request and redirecting to an alternative logon page with your comment fields:

```
public class CommentAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var form = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Form;
        var commentNamePrompt = form.Get("commentNamePrompt");
        var commentEmailPrompt = form.Get("commandEmailPrompt");
        var commentBodyInput = form.Get("commentBodyInput");
        var url = new UrlHelper(filterContext.RequestContext);
        var logonUrl = url.Action("LogonWithComment", "Account", new { commentNamePrompt, commentEmailPrompt, commentBodyInput });
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(logonUrl);
    }
}
```

The comment fields can be populated into your LogonWithComment view and become part of the logon POST.

It's not a pretty solution. If possible I would look for a way to avoid this situation in the first place.

Comment: ya , this is one alternative but I need to make seperate login page for comment which I think might not be appropriate. Anyway, thanks for alternative solution.